# How do I put a literal vertical bar "|" in a control's Hint property?

Tags: delphi, tooltip, delphi-xe2

I have an application that allows the users to enter a regular expression (that they craft) to parse a repository of documents.  The results of the search are displayed in a TTreeView control.  I want to set the TreeView's Hint property (not each Treenode) to the regular expression that was used, but the problem I'm having is that the regular expression can have a pipe (`|`) character within it (regex OR), which Delphi interprets as the separation between the hint and long hint.  I tried replacing each occurrence of `|` with `||` hoping it would have the same effect as using `&&` rather than `&` (such as in menu items) to no avail.

Is there any way to embed a `|` within a hint without it being interpreted as the separator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exact but perhaps near enough

```
 Component.Hint := Stringreplace(TheHintText,'|',#5,[rfReplaceAll]);
```

Comment: The unicode character U+00A6 is the broken pipe, `¦`. Perhaps useful as exchange char.

Comment: Instead of using `StringReplace()` like this, you should use the `TApplication.OnShowHint` event, or subclass the `TTreeView.WindowProc` to intercept the `CM_HINTSHOW` message, to customize the final `THintInfo.HintStr` text that gets shown in the hint window.